# bad anti-aliasing for freestyle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle, antialiasing

[image: bad anti-alaising]

Is there a way to improve anti-aliasing in freestyle?  I'm using cycles and 30 samples. It's pretty ugly.

Comment: I think that freestyle is based on a single depth/normal pass, completely indepedendent from cycles, You probably need to render in double resolution and downscale later.